# Legit? Two foreign keys referencing the same primary key

Tags: sql, database-design

Just as an update for Cliffs, Thanks ChaosPandion for the template.

Person
    PersonID Int PK

Network
    PersonID Int PK FK
    OtherPersonID Int PK FK

OR

Person
    PersonID Int PK

Network
    PersonID Int PK FK
    FriendID Int PK FK

Friend
    FriendID Int PK
    OtherPersonID Int FK

++++++
Original Post Below
++++++

Hi All,

I'm a web developer and have recently started a project with a company. Currently, I'm working with their DBA on getting the schema laid out for the site, and we've come to a disagreement regarding the design on a couple tables, and I'd like some opinions on the matter.

Basically, we are working on a site that will implement a "friends" network. All users of the site will be contained in a table tblUsers with (PersonID int identity PK, etc).

What I am wanting to do is to create a second table, tblNetwork, that will hold all of the relationships between users, with (NetworkID int identity PK, Owners_PersonID int FK, Friends_PersonID int FK, etc). Or conversely, remove the NetworkID, and have both the Owners_PersonID and Friends_PersonID shared as the Primary key.

This is where the DBA has his problem. Saying that "he would only implement this kind of architecture in a data warehousing schema, and not for a website, and this is just another example of web developers trying to take the easy way out."

Now obviously, his remark was a bit inflammatory, and that have helped motivate me to find an suitable answer, but more so, I'd just like to know how to do it right. I've been developing databases and programming for over 10 years, have worked with some top-notch minds, and have never heard this kind of argument.

What the DBA is wanting to do is instead of storing both the Owners_PersonId and Friends_PersonId in the same table, is to create a third table tblFriends to store the Friends_PersonId, and have the tblNetwork have (NetworkID int identity PK, Owner_PersonID int FK, FriendsID int FK(from TBLFriends)). All that tblFriends would house would be (FriendsID int identity PK, Friends_PersonID(related back to Persons)).

To me, creating the third table is just excessive in nature, and does nothing but create an alias for the Friends_PersonID, and cause me to have to add (what I view as unneeded) joins to all my queries, not to mention the extra cycles that will be necessary to perform the join on every query.

I understand that technically, what he is wanting is possible, but is it inline with best practice? What would be best practice?

Thanks for reading, appreciate comments.

Ryan

Comment: I think you have a little too much back story in your question :)

Comment: You're probably right. I'll work on that. :)

Comment: Option 1 appears correct to me.  Why did the DBA suggest he would do it one way for a data warehouse and a different way for a web site?

Comment: You've got me, it seemed a red herring to me.

Comment: @Larry Lustig - I'm not a DBA but my understanding is that in a data warehouse, tables grow to be much larger and the speed of reading data ends up being more important (for generating reports). Since de-normalizing your tables can help to improve performance (as mentioned, less joins), the trade-off can be worth it in some situations for data warehouse type applications. 

Meanwhile for web sites, it's more important that the relationships between data are clear for all developers. That way, your team will make fewer mistakes in updates/selects as integrity is enforced in a stricter manner.

Comment: The DBA was probably referring to denormalization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) with his "data warehouse" comment. Under certain high-load situations redundancy can improve performance and ends up being an acceptable trade-off with losing some normalization.

Comment: It appears to me that that DBA's solution, as presented by the OP, is less normal than the OP's suggestion.  Yet the DBA is suggesting that he'd only use the normal version in a data warehouse.

Comment: @Larry Lustig - Yeah, you may be right. I was actually basing my answer off of the answers below (not based on the OP) and was just assuming the DBA meant to have him normalize his table. 


Yes, I know, assuming is bad. I hear this too often from people :)

Comment: I have met some DBA's with advanced degrees yet who don't know the correct meaning of normalization and denormalization.

Comment: Thanks all, I believe I've got what I was looking for. The solution that Andomar and Bill Karwin posted seems the most appropriate.

Comment: Just as an update. After presenting the ideas in this thread to my dba, this is what I got back.

Person              PersonID PK
FriendList          Person FK (renamed to FriendListID)
FriendListEntry     FriendListEntryID, Person FK (as FriendListID), EntryPersonID PK

So basically, and unwittingly, the guy has given me exactly what I asked for in the first place, with the addition of a horrible tumor hanging off the side of it head. Sigh.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand you right, You're proposing:

```
Person              PersonID PK
FriendList          FriendListID, OwnerID, PersonID
```

The DBA proposes:

```
Person              PersonID PK
FriendList          FriendListID, OwnerID
FriendListEntry     FriendListID, PersonID
```

Your approach would require multiple rows for each friend in the list.  This would repeat OwnerID multiple times, violating normal form.  The DBA's solution is more normalized, having only values that depend on FriendListID in the FriendList table.

The best practice here is to be good friends with the DBA.  I'd go with his solution because it doesn't matter much, and you're sure to need him later on.

Comment: I fail to see how adding a third table makes the schema more normalized.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: The two-table solution violates second normal form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) by repeating OwnerID for each friend in the list

Comment: I've updated the OP with shorthand of the tables, for clarification. Edit-which is exactly as Andomar listed above.

Comment: Please explain why this does not apply to `FriendListID`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: It does not apply to FriendListID because FriendListID is a foreign key.  The difference becomes clearer if there was more information tied to a FriendList, for example a name, create date, type (Work/Private), and privacy information.  The two-table approach would repeat all of that

Comment: Well I'll be damned you convinced me. My guess is the DBA is just an arrogant jerk. He should have explained his reasoning.

Comment: @Ryan: What you have in your post does not appear to be identical to what Andomar has above. In your post you have FriendID as the primary key of the "Friend" table, meaning you would have a new FriendID for each entry and thus a new row in the "Network" table for each friend. In Andomar's example FriendListID is primary in what would be your "Network" table, but foreign in what would be your "Friend" table.

Comment: @Robert - You are correct, I misread what he had there. What I've posted at the top of the OP is what the DBA proposes. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Ryan: Sounds like Andomar's design is what the DBA should be proposing anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The only schema that makes sense to me is this:

```
Person
    PersonID Int PK

Friend
    PersonID Int PK FK
    OtherPersonID Int PK FK
```

So you might have a procedure called `FriendList` that executes this nice clean query:

```
Select Person.*
From Friend
    Inner Join Person On Friend.OtherPersonID = Person.PersonID
Where Friend.PersonID = @PersonID;
```

*I do not condone selecting all columns.*

Comment: So how would you store the owner of the friend list?

Comment: @Andomar - Not quite sure I follow.

Comment: Each network has a `Owner_PersonID`.  If I understand the question right, the main difference between the DBA and the poster's solution is where to store that information

Comment: Right, and that's how I'm looking at it; which is probably where the comment about doing it the "easy" way generated, lol.

Basically, he hasn't provided anything concrete regarding his position, but since he's their fulltime dba, his word is final. I just want to know if I'm wrong in wanting a simple two table design. Or if there really is some logical reason for his want of three tables. 

I kind of feel like this is one of those secret tests employers give to see if employees really know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Your design violates [Third Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), if `Network.Owners_PersonID` is stored redundantly for a network.

But I don't understand how the DBA's design actually helps.  I would have expected `Friends` to be the many-to-many table between `Users` and `Networks`:

```
CREATE TABLE tblUsers (
  PersonID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE tblNetworks (
  NetworkID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Owner_PersonID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES tblUsers
);

CREATE TABLE tblFriends (
  NetworkID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES tblNetworks,
  FriendID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES tblUsers,
  PRIMARY KEY(NetworkID, FriendID)
);
```

In other words, you have a simple many-to-many relationship:

```
Users ----<- Friends ->---- Networks
```

And additionally, `Networks` references `Users` just to identify the owner of the given network.  This way there's only one row for a given network, so you can't create an update anomaly by changing the owner of the network on some rows.

I don't think this is splitting the entities into separate tables excessively.  You can still get a list of friends for a given network:

```
SELECT ... FROM Networks n JOIN Friends f ON (n.NetworkID=f.NetworkID)
```

You can get all of a user's friends from all networks this way (pass the given user's id for the `?` parameter):

```
SELECT ... FROM Friends u 
JOIN Friends f ON (u.NetworkID=f.NetworkID)
WHERE u.UserID = ?
```

In your original design, it's pretty much the same:

```
SELECT ... FROM Networks u
JOIN Networks f ON (u.Owner_UserID=f.Owner_UserID)
WHERE u.FriendID = ?
```

But the advantage is that you've eliminated the possible update anomaly.

Comment: See, I can work with what you've got above. I actually prefer it.

It makes me wonder if the DBA may have just "typo'd" the schema, and has been arguing with me not realizing what he's got on paper.

Comment: Have you had a face-to-face discussion about this database design, and done some sketching on a whiteboard or something?  If you're only communicating by email, that's pretty inefficient and prone to misunderstandings.

Comment: A bit of nitpicking: repeating groups violate **second** normal form.  Third normal form requires that each element only depends on the key

Comment: @Andomar: Hmm.  I didn't think this was a repeating-groups issue, it's an update-anomaly issue.

Comment: Well as I understand it the update anomaly comes with violating second normal form?

Comment: But second normal form has to do with compound keys.  Go look at the example scenario on the wikipedia page for Third Normal Form.  It's pretty similar to this scenario with the OP's original design for the Networks table.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am wanting to do is to create a
>   second table, tblNetwork, that will
>   hold all of the relationships between
>   users, with (NetworkID int identity
>   PK, Owners_PersonID int FK,
>   Friends_PersonID int FK, etc). Or
>   conversely, remove the NetworkID, and
>   have both the Owners_PersonID and
>   Friends_PersonID shared as the Primary
>   key.

I don't see any problem with this.  And I agree that the `NetworkID` is superfluous -- the two FKs are the natural key for the table, and so you should just use them as the primary key, unless you have some performance reason why you need to refer to specific relationships by a surrogate ID (which you don't seem to have in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I say do it your way.  Having that third table makes the programming part more of a pain.